# Determining the basis and dimensions of a 2x2 matrix vector (sub)space

Tags: linear-algebra

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tobcy.png) subspace and I have to determine a basis and its dimension.
$$U=\textrm{Sp}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1&2\\-1&2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}3&0\\2&-2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\-2&0\end{pmatrix}\right\}\subseteq\cal M(\mathbb R)$$ I got that the first 3 matrices form a basis, however I don't understand how to determine the dimension and the solution to the problem just says that it's 4 with no other explanation. Isn't the dimension equal to the number of terms that form a basis or is that definition only applied to vectors with one columns. I just started Linear Algebra and I am genuinely confused because so far in class we've only worked with "regular" vectors(the ones that only have a column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine the dimension first. The maximum dimension can be $4$, if the four matrices are linearly independent. If that's the case, then the 4 matrices form a basis.
$$a\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}-1&2\\-1&2\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}3&0\\2&-2\end{pmatrix}+d\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\-2&0\end{pmatrix}=0$$
You can easily see that this system has only the trivial solution $a=b=c=d=0$, so the matrices are independent.

Answer (score 1):

The first $3$ matrices do *not* form a basis, since the $4$ matrices are linearly independent; this follows from the fact that$$\begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 & 2 \\ 3 & 0 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & 2 & -2 & 0\end{vmatrix}=4\ne0.$$And any set of $4$ linearly independent vectors spans a $4$-dimensional space.